# Problems clamping quaternion rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, clamp

I've done some reasearch on this, but nothing seem to work in a proper manner. Hopefully someone can shed light on what I'm doing wrong.

In this 2D Unity game I'm working on I want the cannons to follow the mouse and rotate around the z-axis. The current code does exactly that, but I would also like to clamp the rotation.

```
Vector3 dir = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - dir.normalized, Vector3.forward);
    targetRotation.x = 0;
    targetRotation.y = 0;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed * 10);
```

I have tried using `if`-statements to limit rotation:

```
if(eulerAngle > 65 && eulerAngle < 295) //pseudo code
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed * 10)
```

This works, but locks the barrel of the cannon at either 65 or 295 degrees. I've had no luck using `if`statements to "unlock" the barrel rotation.

I've also tried a similar statement using Quaternions:

```
float amountToRotate = Quaternion.Angle (transform.rotation, targetRotation);
```

I guess, due to the way quaternions work, the angle increases even by moving further away from the target. Similar to numbers on the complex plane?

The `mathf.clamp` function gave me no luck at all.

There's probably an easy fix to all these solutions to the problem, but I just can't seem to work it out.

Edit: I would prefer to use `mathf.clamp` as that seems to be the "cleanest" solution.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with something similar to if(eulerAngle > 65) {transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f,0.0f,64.9f)}

Comment: I retraced my steps and did the same as earlier today -- and now it's working. However, I get some weird movement at the edges as the rotation is constantly bouncing between two values.

Comment: So, block the user from going that way if the value is reached. But that is something for you to find out yourself or how to do, or another question :)

Comment: It solved one problem and caused a new one, but I did get what I asked for. ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your `if` state logic.

Lets break it up in some logical blocks:

- If the value is bigger then 65 > check the next block

If this is not the case that means the value is under or equal to 65 and the `if` wont run. In the next block (if the value is over 65)

- If the value is below 295 > execute if statement

if this is not the case that means the value is bigger or equal to 295.

First off all I would advice to turn your if statement to include equal to

```
if(eulerAngle >= 65 && eulerAngle <= 295)
```

This gives us a few checks less to think about. Now we know, if your cannon rotation freezes it is because the angle is lower then 65 ( < 65) or higher then 295 (> 295).

For the if statement to be able to continue you will want the value to be in between the values again, because you added the = check to the values as well. You can now just set them to 65 or 295 according to which one is out of range. Sample to give you an idea:

```
else if( eulerAngle < 65)
    eulerAngle = 65;
```